# MeteorJS: How to get title data via server method by given id array

Tags: javascript, reactjs, meteor

What is the 'meteor'-way to get a document title by a given ID?

**Collection (Articles)**

```
{
    '_id'         : 'Dn59y87PGhkJXpaiZ',
    'title'       : 'Sample Article',
    'slug'        : 'sample-article'
}
```

**client**

```
render() {
    const data = [ 
        { _id: 'Dn59y87PGhkJXpaiZ' },
        { _id: 'kJXpaiZDn59y87PGh' }
        { _id: 'y87PGhkJXpaiZDn59' }
    ]
    return (
        <List>
            {
                data.map(r => {
                    return <List.Item>r._id</List.Item>
                })
            }
    )
}
```

With this I will get this output:

```
<List>
    <List.Item>Dn59y87PGhkJXpaiZ</List.Item>
    <List.Item>kJXpaiZDn59y87PGh</List.Item>
    <List.Item>y87PGhkJXpaiZDn59</List.Item>
</List>
```

Now I want to display the title instead of the id. So normally I would do

```
data.map(r => {
    const title = Articles.findOne({ _id: r._id }).title
    return <List.Item>title</List.Item>
})
```

But the problem is, that `data` is a dynamic dataset and I can't/don't want to publish the complete Articles collection. Right now there is no subscription, so I don't get any results for the title.
So I think I have to do a server side call.

```
Meteor.call('getTitle', r._id, function(err, res) {
    console.log(res)
})
```

But then I'll get the result in the callback function. So how do I get these into the list? Also I want to avoid multiple method calls. I think it would be better to send `data` and get all titles on server side and then build the list.

Comment: I use [Sessions](https://docs.meteor.com/api/session.html) to handle that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you can/want to use a non async call, don't pass a callback to the Meteor.call() method:

```
data.map(r => {
  const title = Meteor.call('getTitle',r._id);
  return <List.Item>title</List.Item>
})
```

As stated in the [docs](https://docs.meteor.com/api/methods.html):

> If you do not pass a callback on the server, the method invocation will block until the method is complete. It will eventually return the return value of the method, or it will throw an exception if the method threw an exception.

Answer (score 0):

To fetch and render the data meteor way you have to use the package called [react-meteor-data](https://atmospherejs.com/meteor/react-meteor-data) to create **createContainer**.

For example if you were to use it then you would be able to pass it directly to the component as props.

```
export default createContainer((props) => {
  Meteor.subscribe('questions');
  return {
    questions: Questions.findOne({_id: props.match.params.id})
  };
}, QuestionDo);
```